# .NET 6.0: new Blazor project throws Websocket error

Tags: c#, nginx, websocket, blazor

I am running currently a webserver with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and a Blazor project.
Recently when upgrading to .NET 6.0 I encountered (even with a blank Blazor project) some problems with a websocket error message in the browser only when deployed on my webserver (see message below).

Locally (on Windows 11 x64, VS 22 Preview 4) there are no error messages...

Webserver: Debian 10 x64, .NET 6.0 SDK installed, running on NGINX with websockets enabled (reverse proxy).

Do I miss out on something or is it a problem with the current state of .NET 6.0 and NGINX? I already tried to access the webpage locally on the debian server and the same error message occurs.

Help would be much appreciated!

Greetings!

***Error messages within order:***

```
Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://192.168.178.35/_blazor'.
```

---

```
blazor.server.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.178.35/_blazor?id=wnPt_fXa9H4Jpia530vPWQ' failed:
```

---

```
Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
```

---

```
Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
```

---

```
Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.
```

Comment: Do you always get the error or only sometimes?

Comment: Always and its always the same.

Comment: Looks like a NGINX configuration issue. Not my area. But does it allow non-SSL?

Comment: Good question, I will have a look. Is there a problem with non-SSL? Normally I have everything forwarded to SSL.

Comment: I looked it up, SSL as well as non-SSL is available. Problem still there.

Comment: I also tried the same configuration back on ASP.NET Core 3.1 - no errors, everything fine.

Comment: Any solution for IIS 10?

Comment: Disable Long Polling Fallback Transport for Blazor Server #470 
   https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/470

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution described again, maybe a little bit more convenient:

To fix this problem, I changed in the site-configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available) of nginx the following variables:

```
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```

to

```
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

For me this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Bullets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18088603/bullets) response and https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

Edit your site configuration on /etc/nginx/sites-available

Replace:

```
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
```

With:

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```