# Blazor Server web socket error for some clients

Tags: websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side

We have a Blazor Server application (.NET 6) with hundreds of users. We have one site (so far) that gets a web socket error when trying to connect:

> WebSocket connection to [our url] failed. There was an error with the
> transport...endpoint may not be and endpoint, the ConnectionId may not
> be present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking websockets.

We have websockets enabled and all but this site connect without error. In fact, if the user goes home they can connect fine. We do have a security front end that re-routes after authentication, but again this is working fine for everyone else.

I am looking for client side configuration issues that might cause this? They also are able to connect to our framework/MVC apps without issue.

Comment: Take a look to this solution for proxy issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937709/net-6-0-new-blazor-project-throws-websocket-error